# Making 2 images float right and directly under each other without container div

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have a small problem creating a website from a design.

The designer used text wrap to get a text around an image (FFS!!!!!). Now I came up with a idea how to solve this on the website by dividing the image in 2 separate images like:

[image: 2 images so the text can float around it]

Now I trying to do this. But when I give `float:right` to the images they go next to each other instead of directly below each other like:

[image]

Now there are a lot of threads about this problem. And they suggest to put a dive around them. But this is not possible for me because I seperated them to create different widths and putting a div around them will bring me back to the original problem.

Does anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float the images right as you already did and just clear them at the same time.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
}

img {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff" alt>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x150/000/fff" alt>
    <p>
            Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue.
    </p>
    <p>
            Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
    </p>
    <p>
            Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.
    </p>
</div>
```

`<p>` aren't necessary, also works with vanilla text.

Comment: Wow! I tryd the clear before but somehow I think ti didnt got it or something! works right now so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

take a `main_div` in this div write code for this:

```
<div class="main_div">
  <div class="txtdiv">
  </div>

  <div class="imgdiv">
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

your `css` will be like this:

```
 .main_div:
  {
   width:100%;
  }
.txtdiv
    {
     width:45%;
     float:left;
    }
    .imgdiv
    {
     width:45%;
     float:left;
    }
    .clr
    {
      clear:both;
    }
```

This will work for sure. I have checked..

Comment: This way both images get the same width because of the container? As stated in my post I need a solution which keeps the width of the divs in place.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your issue on codepen. http://codepen.io/Quantum/pen/NxLzWW

HTML

```
<div class="images">
<img width="100" height="100" src="">
<img width="200" height="100" src="">
</div>
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
```

CSS

```
body{max-width:300px}
.images{margin-left:10px}
img{float:right}
```

Give the correct dimensions and use I could fix your current issue.